# HTML select option should create dynamic select options based on value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create dynamic select option where the select option value selection  populates dynamic select options. Example if user select 3, has a result it should create 3 another additional select options has you can see by following this url image represent has rooms

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ddTest").change(function(){          
     var value = $("#ddTest option:selected").val();
     if (value === '') return;
     var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
     //displays the selected option div
     theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
     //disbales the selected option
     $("#ddTest option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $(this).val('');
 });   
 $("div a.remove").click(function () { 
     var value = $(this).attr('rel');
     var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
     //enables the disabled option
     $("#ddTest option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
     //hides the selected option div
     $(this).parent().slideUp(function() { $(this).addClass("hidden"); });
 });
});


    <div class="selectContainer">
        <select id="ddTest">
            <option value="">- Select Option-</option>
            <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden isOption1">Option 1 <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option1">remove</a></div>
    <div class="hidden isOption2">Option 2 <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a></div>
    <div class="hidden isOption3">Option 3 <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option3">remove</a></div>
```

The output possibly should represent has you can see the rooms drop-down where it populates number of select option has you can see in this image

[image: pic]

please follow the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cubo/2m9351ev/

this is not the actual output i am expecting , and i am expecting the output has i metnioned before Ex: if user select 3 rooms it should populate 3 another additional select options just like the picture.

Comment: Put your code in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we could edit it live and help you fix your problem.

Comment: Will take a look a bit later. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: many thanks for your kind responds !

Comment: Hi ! i need a help to solve this problem which i came across  with : Problem Statement :   In my web application i have a select option has room has you can see the image at the bottom and i wanted a java script / jquery program where this select option can populate dynamic select options based on primary select option selected value , just the manner shown below in the image . Ex: if user select value  4 has a result it should create 4 additional select options and at the same time user select value 1 it should create 1 select option simply based on user selects the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a quick and dirty example. Modify it to suit your needs accordingly. I'd add in code explanation later, when I have some time.

```js
$(function() {
    
    var $eachRoomContainer = $("#select-guests");
    var $eachRoomHidden = $("#guests-each-room-hidden");
    var $eachRoomSelects = $eachRoomHidden.find(" > .guests-each-room");
    
    $("#ddTest").change(function() {    
        var rooms = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0,
         $allEachRooms = $eachRoomContainer.find(".guests-each-room"),
         totalEachRoooms = $allEachRooms.length,
         $temp = $();
  
        $allEachRooms.show();
        if (totalEachRoooms > rooms) {
   $allEachRooms.filter(function() {
             return $(this).index() >= rooms;
            }).hide();
        }
        
  var deltaRooms = totalEachRoooms >= rooms && 0 || (rooms - totalEachRoooms);
        for (var i=0; i<deltaRooms; i++) {
            $temp = $temp.add($eachRoomSelects.clone());
        }
  $eachRoomContainer.append($temp);
    });
});
```

```css
#guests-each-room-hidden { display: none; }
.guests-each-room { margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-total-rooms">
    <select id="ddTest">
        <option value="0">Select Rooms</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <div id="guests-each-room-hidden">
        <div class="guests-each-room">
            <select class="room-adults">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select class="room-children">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="select-guests"></div>
```

Comment: Hi lshettyl, thanks a lot! i tried many attempts but i couldn't get the expected outcome and you just helped me to fix this problem, once again many thanks and best regards ! along with i like to endorse your skills and i a slightly new to stack-overflow